# JSON Decoding using Go fails

Tags: json, go, decoding

i have some problems decoding the body of a http response. The response I get from using Insomnia looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "monitoring",
    "instances": [
      {
        "host": "ite00716.local",
        "id": "2058b934-720f-47c5-a1da-3d1535423b83",
        "port": 8080
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "app1",
    "instances": [
      {
        "host": "172.20.10.2",
        "id": "bc9a5859-8dda-418a-a323-11f67fbe1a71",
        "port": 8081
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When I use the following go code, the struct I decode to is empty. I'm not sure why. Please help me!

```golang
type Service struct {
    Name      string     `json:"name"`
    Instances []Instance `json:"instances"`
}

type Instance struct {
    Host string `json:"host"`
    Id   string `json:"id"`
    Port int    `json:"port"`
}

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8080/services")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var s Service

    json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&s)

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Comment: Check the error returned by `Decoder.Decode()`. Any time you're encountering a problem, *check your error returns*.

Comment: Your input JSON is a JSON array, so you have to unmarshal it into a Go slice, not into a single struct value. Try `var s []Service` or `var s []*Service`.

Comment: nit-pick, but `http.Response.Body` implements the `ReadCloser`interface, no need for the `defer resp.Body.Close()` call IIRC

Answer (score 4):

Your json response is array of service

```
var s []Service
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be that your variable is a Service, while your json represent an array of "Service"s.

Try declaring s as:

```
var s []Service;
```